# Is there a bug in controller attribute binding

Tags: dart, angular-dart

I have a parent controller and a child controller and both have `publishAs: ctrl` (the same name). If I try to use a parameter from the parent-ctrl to give a value to a child-ctrl's attribute, the attribute will use a value from child-ctrl.

Here is the example, where my-ctrl1 and my-ctrl2 works as expected, but my-ctrl3 doesn't.

The output from my-ctrl3 should be: "Child3 attribute message: parent", but now it is: "Child3 attribute message: child3"

I think this bug is related to this question also: [Can I put ng-if directive on an element which also binds to a controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22314313/can-i-put-ng-if-directive-on-an-element-which-also-binds-to-a-controller)

ang.dart:

```dart
import 'package:angular/angular.dart';

@NgController(selector: '[my-ctrl1]', publishAs: 'ctrl')
class MyCtrlController {
  String m1="child1";
}

@NgController(selector: '[my-ctrl2]', publishAs: 'ctrl2')
class MyCtrl2Controller {
  @NgOneWay('message')
  String message;

  String m1="child2";
}

@NgController(selector: '[my-ctrl3]', publishAs: 'ctrl')
class MyCtrl3Controller {
  @NgOneWay('message')
  String message;

  String m1="child3";
}

@NgController(selector: '[parent-ctrl]', publishAs: 'ctrl')
class ParentCtrlController {
  String m1="parent";
}

class MyAppModule extends Module {
  MyAppModule() {
    type(MyCtrlController);
    type(MyCtrl2Controller);
    type(MyCtrl3Controller);
    type(ParentCtrlController);
  }
}

void main() {
  ngBootstrap(module: new MyAppModule());
}
```

ang.html:

```dart
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html ng-app>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>ng-model test</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="ang.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div parent-ctrl>
      <p>Parent m1: {{ctrl.m1}}</p><br>
      <div my-ctrl1>
        <p>Child1 m1: {{ctrl.m1}}</p><br>
      </div>
      <div my-ctrl2 message="ctrl.m1">
        <p>Child2 attribute message: {{ctrl2.message}}</p>
        <p>Child2 m1: {{ctrl2.m1}}</p><br>
      </div>
      <div my-ctrl3 message="ctrl.m1">
        <p>Child3 attribute message: {{ctrl.message}}</p>
        <p>Child3 m1: {{ctrl.m1}}</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <script src="packages/shadow_dom/shadow_dom.min.js"></script>
    <script type="application/dart" src="ang.dart"></script>
    <script src="packages/browser/dart.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why do you expect the output of `my-ctrl3` to be: "Child3 attribute message: parent"? "Child3 attribute message: {{ctrl.message}} is within the `my-ctrl3` scope. You might try `{{ctrl.$parent.message}}`

Comment: I'm thinking that the child scope will begin after enclosing tag (>)  in <div my-ctrl3 message="ctrl.m1">. My idea is that the whole div tag is an entry point to child scope. Basically I don't see any point why the child scope should be included in the div tag. If the child scope is now correct, then tutorials and etc. should emphasize the unique naming of controllers. In my example my-ctrl2 uses unique controller names and it's of course working (as stated in my original question). I'm just curious to know what other users think about this behavior.

Comment: Ok, I think I understand now what you mean and I think you are right.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer thank you for confirmation. I have opened a new issue: https://github.com/angular/angular.dart/issues/719